# How close a window from another in pyside2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

I have 2 windows: MainWindow and a normal window, I have a button in MainWindow that open the second window and I have a button in the second window, I want when clicked the button in the second window close the MainWindow. The two windows are in separate class and files.

> This is the MainWindow

```
from select_company_controller import SelectCompany
from views.main_window_view import MainWindowForm
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import sys

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, MainWindowForm):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.open_select_company_window)

    def open_select_company_window(self):
        self.window = SelectCompany()
        self.window.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

> And this is the second window

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from views.select_company_view import SelectCompanyForm


class SelectCompany(QtWidgets.QWidget, SelectCompanyForm):

    def __init__(self):
        super(SelectCompany, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.button.clicked.connect(close_main_window)

    def close_main_window(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Why use 2 separate Windows -- why not just replace the Central Widget with the new Central Widget you plan to use -- opening a second window is a lot of unnecessary excess overhead ??

Comment: For maintenance, each window will have much more code.

Comment: Yes but if both are based on a QMainWindow -- then you can make exterior classes for the CentralWidget -- then simply swap them and the MenuTool Bar (should that also be needed to classed) I am not just blowing smoke -- when I make my MainWindow I always sub-class CentralPanel as well as the MenuToolBar so that should I want to swap them out for a different set I do so easily and even from within code -- and these can be very complex self-contained classes

Comment: Basically the QMainWindow is just a container handler for the true Gui which is your CenterWidget Object

Comment: Show me a litter sample of what you want to say or a link

Comment: Oh I need to create an account for discord so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

**main.py**

```
import sys
#from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

from select_company_controller import SelectCompany
#from views.main_window_view import MainWindowForm


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow): #, MainWindowForm):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
#        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowTitle('Main Window')
        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)        

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Open SelectCompany')
        button.clicked.connect(self.open_select_company_window)

        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        grid.addWidget(button)

    def open_select_company_window(self):
        self.window = SelectCompany(self)
        self.window.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show() #showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**select_company_controller.py**

```
#from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
#from views.select_company_view import SelectCompanyForm


class SelectCompany(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):   #QWidget, SelectCompanyForm):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SelectCompany, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.setWindowTitle('SelectCompany')

        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Close MainWindow')
        button.clicked.connect(self.close_main_window)

        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        grid.addWidget(button)

    def close_main_window(self):
        self.parent.hide()
```

[image]

---

**Update**

```
#from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
#from views.select_company_view import SelectCompanyForm


class SelectCompany(QtWidgets.QWidget):   #, SelectCompanyForm):                  #  <--- QWidget
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SelectCompany, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Window |  QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)   #  <---

        self.setWindowTitle('SelectCompany')

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Close MainWindow')
        button.clicked.connect(self.close_main_window)

        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(button)

    def close_main_window(self):
        self.parent.hide()
```

Comment: I am going to try it

Comment: The second window appears without the background and title bar. Maybe is because inherit from a file that I generated with the designer.

Comment: there is no other way to do what I want?

Comment: @Arthur I added an updated module `select_company_controller.py`

Comment: Okay it might work but dang it sure looks like the harder way to go about it doing it.